# Internet explorer fetch data from cache after deleting object in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer, caching

When deleting entity from a list, IE9- is not reading data from DB again but it fetches the old data from cache. This is working in every other browsers but not on IE browsers. How to avoid this, in another word how to disable cache in this controller or in whole angular app?

```
angular.module('rmaClientApp')
    .controller('RmaListCtrl', function ($scope, $location, rmaService, rmaStatusSvc, $routeParams) {
$scope.deleteRma = function (rmaId) {
    $scope.deletedStatus = $scope.statuses[4];
    $scope.rma = rmaService.delete({id: rmaId}, function (data) {
        $scope.rmas = rmaService.query();
        $location.path('/rma-list');
     }, function (err) {
            console.log('ERROR in deleting RMA: ' +err);    

         });
};
```

EDIT: I disabled cache from the JPA Eclipselink and now it refreshes the list, but if I go somewhere else in my app and go back to the list, it reads the list from cache again and the deleted object is again there. It is deleted in DB.

EDIT2:
**AngularJS service**

```
'use strict';

angular.module('rmaServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('rmaService', ['$resource',
        function ($resource) {
            return $resource(
                    '/RMAServerMav/webresources/com.rako.entity.rma/:id',

                    {},
                    {

                        findRange:{
                            url: '/RMAServerMav/webresources/com.rako.entity.rma/:from/:to',        
                            method: 'GET', 

                            params: {from: '@from', to: '@to'},
                            isArray:true}
                    });
        }]);
```

Comment: What does your service look like? Are you using ngResource?

Comment: Yes, I am using  resource get method for the default set, so no code at all in my service for get all.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Your service will be needed to answer the question since your service is providing the data and deleting the item.

Comment: @AlexS - It is working like that in every othere browser but not in IE. I edited my question with the service.

Comment: OK now I understand your comment. How is your list initialized? By going back you mean browser-navigation-back?

Comment: No, I mean just navigating back to list page later, not with back-button. I will add the list initialising later when I am in another machine, but I think that then it shouldn't work in any other browser either if there is some problem?

Comment: I agree that I would expect every browser to handle things the same way, but the init-code is IMHO the next logical choice to look for possible issues. By the way another idea: Is your controller initialized again if you navigate back?